# Query fields won't separate when getting more than one at a time

Tags: php, sql

When I run this query, it works fine but the individual fields would pull out. Like `ThumbFilePath` and `Title`.

If I run the query with only one field like:

```
$result = mysql_query("select ThumbFilePath from artwork where SCID = $SCID") or die(mysql_error());
```

It works fine. Any ideas why I can't pull the other fields?

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'pdartist2';
    $table = 'artowrk';
    // query
    $result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder from artwork where SCID = $SCID") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        foreach($row as $cell)
        {
            echo "<div id='thumb_container'>";        
            echo "
<a href='gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID'>
 <img src='http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/$ThumbFilePath' title='Enlarge' alt='Enlarge' border='0'>
</a>
";
            echo "$Title";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Wat is the output u get when u run ...  Can u show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you'll ALWAYS need to dereference the columns you need.  For example:

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
      $aid = $row['AID'];
      $tpath= $row['ThumbFilePath'];
      $title = $row['title'];
      ...



<?php
  $dbname = 'pdartist2';
  $table = 'artowrk';
  // query
  $sql = "select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder from artwork where SCID = $SCID";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $AID = $row['AID'];
    $ThumbFilePath= $row['ThumbFilePath'];
    $Title = $row['Title'];
    $DisplayOrder = $row['DisplayOrder'];
    echo "<div id='clear'></div>";
    echo "<div id='thumb_container'>";
    echo "<a href='gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID'><img src='http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/$ThumbFilePath' title='Enlarge' alt='Enlarge' border='0'></a>";
    echo "<div id='name_spacer'></div>";
    echo "<div id='thumbdesc'>";
    echo "$Title";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: $result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder from artwork where SCID = $SCID") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
 $AID = $rows['AID'];
      $ThumbFilePath= $rows['ThumbFilePath'];
     $Title = $rows['Title'];
 $DisplayOrder = $rows['DisplayOrder'];
 {
 foreach($row as $cell)
 {
 echo "<div id='thumb_container'>";
 echo "<a href='gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID'><img src='http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/$ThumbFilePath' title='Enlarge' alt='Enlarge' border='0'></a>";
 echo "$Title";
}
}
}
mysql_free_result($result);?>

Comment: My bad - I mistyped "$rows[]" instead of "$row[]".  Try the revised version.